# Setting options outside of the constructor in FineUploader

Tags: constructor, fine-uploader

My question is how would I set options outside of the constructor, if possible?  For example, my request object depends of the type of file selected, so I have to build that object after the construction of the FineUploader object. Also, I want to set certain callbacks outside of the constructor, and have tried stuff like:

```
this.uploader = 
        new qq.FineUploaderBasic({button: btnAF, 
        debug: true,
        multiple: false,
        callbacks:{
           onSubmitted: lang.hitch(this, this._addFile)
        },
        autoUpload: false});
```

And then some where else in the code:

```
var request = { endpoint: '/some/url/yada/yada/yada'};
this.uploader.request = request;
this.uploader.callbacks.onComplete = function(id, .... ) {  alert ('Woo hoo!'); }
this.uploader.uploadStoredFiles();
```

However, it doesn't seem to work like this, and I didn't see any "setters" in the API doc that would allow me to set these on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

The setEndpoint method lets you set the endpoint at any time for a specific file or for all files. It's not clear why you would want to replace your callback handlers on the fly. Callback handlers you supply are functions, which means the logic associated with each callback is already dynamic. Adjust the behavior of a handler based on the parameters passed into the handler, or some other in scope variable you control.

Comment: I suppose I can get around the callback issue.  I see I can set parameters on the fly, so I may be OK.  Thanks again, Ray!